# App has no attribute 'counter', Two functions trying to work together

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a counter that works is not be recognized by other functions. I want this counter to work in any other function.

```
def buttoncounter(self):
     self.showthis =  str([self.videofirstbutton.get(),
                    self.videosecondbutton.get(),
                    self.videothirdbutton.get(),
                    self.videofourthbutton.get(),
                    self.videofifthbutton.get(),
                    self.videosixthbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideofirstbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideosecondbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideothirdbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideofourthbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideofifthbutton.get(),
                    self.homevideosixthbutton.get(), 
                    self.castingfirstbutton.get(),
                    self.castingsecondbutton.get(),
                    self.castingthirdbutton.get(),
                    self.castingfourthbutton.get(),
                    self.castingfifthbutton.get(),
                    self.castingsixthbutton.get()])
     self.counter =  print(self.showthis.count('1'))

def printbutton(self):   
        self.printbutton = Button(self.frame, text="Print Events " + str(self.counter), width=15, command=self.buttoncounter) #str(self.counter)
        self.printbutton.pack( side = LEFT )
```

The error is:

```
line 211, in printbutton
    self.printbutton = Button(self.frame, text="Print Events " + str(self.counter), width=15, command=self.buttoncounter) #str(self.counter)
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'counter'
```

I expect the output of the button to be "Print Events (myanswer)" but it just rejects it all together

Comment: I can't quite tell what code you ran to produce the error that you included. Would you mind including a minimal example that I can run on my computer?

Comment: `self.counter =  print(self.showthis.count('1'))` is wrong, `print` returns `None`. What you may want is an `IntVar` instead. It's hard to decide upon a suitable answer as your code is not complete. [m.c.v.e](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the way to go.

Comment: I dont get none as the return value. I get a value, if i select 2 or 3 it returns that answer when you click the print button.

Comment: The error is telling you that `self.counter` is not defined. That means it is not defined in your `__init__`, and you tried to call `self.counter` before some other methods create it. To solve this easily, add `self.counter=None` during `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul Rooney explained in the comment, the bad line is `self.counter = print(self.showthis.count('1'))`. The `print` function takes strings as input, and writes them to [stdout](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/stdout.htm). Incidentally, in Python all functions that return nothing actually return `None`. So if you decide to store the output of a function returning nothing, you get `None`:

```py
>>> result = print('I\'m headed for your screen!')
I'm headed for your screen!
>>> result is None
True
```

Answer (score -1):

I wasnt sure where to put this

```
from tkinter import *

the_window = Tk()
the_window.title('Entertainment Guide')
the_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas = Canvas(the_window, width = 500, height = 100)
canvas.pack()

class App:

    def buttoncounter(self):
         self.showthis =  str([self.videofirstbutton.get(),
                        self.videosecondbutton.get(),
                        self.videothirdbutton.get(),
                        self.videofourthbutton.get(),
                        self.videofifthbutton.get(),
                        self.videosixthbutton.get()])
         self.counter =  print(self.showthis.count('1'))

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.frame = Frame(the_window)
        self.frame.pack()
        #the_window.geometry("500x120")
        canvas.configure(background='paleturquoise')

        self.videogames = Button(self.frame, text = 'Video Games', fg ='violet', width=15, command=self.create_videogameswindow) 
        self.videogames.pack( side = LEFT ) 

    def printbutton(self):   
        self.printbutton = Button(self.frame, text="Print Events ", width=15, command=self.buttoncounter) #str(self.counter)
        self.printbutton.pack( side = LEFT )

    def create_videogameswindow(self):
        self.a = videogameswindow = Toplevel(the_window)
        self.b = videogameswindow.title('Video Games')
        self.c = videogameswindow.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.heading = Label(videogameswindow, text="Video Game Selector", bg="violet", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.heading.pack()
        self.videofirstbutton = IntVar()
        self.videosecondbutton = IntVar()
        self.videothirdbutton = IntVar()
        self.videofourthbutton = IntVar()
        self.videofifthbutton = IntVar()
        self.videosixthbutton = IntVar()
        self.V1 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videofirstbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.V2 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videosecondbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.V3 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videothirdbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.V4 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videofourthbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.V5 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videofifthbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.V6 = Checkbutton(videogameswindow, text = "Video", variable =self.videosixthbutton, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, bg='violet').pack(anchor=W)
        self.d = videogameswindow.configure(background='violet')
        self.printbutton()

app = App(the_window)
the_window.mainloop()
```

Adjust Print Events accordingly.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? The answer section is only for answers.